# Pass param to mapStateToProps in `connect()`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

How do I pass in a parameter to `mapStateToProps()`?

EG:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, dimenType: string) => {

  var jsonVariable = {}
  for(var i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
    jsonVariable[dimenType + i] = dimenType + i
  }
  console.log(jsonVariable)
  return {
    width1: state.get('width').get('width1').toString(),
    width2: state.get('width').get('width2').toString(),
    width3: state.get('width').get('width3').toString()
  }
}
```

This is the bit I'm unsure of:

```
Width = connect(
  mapStateToProps(/*redux store goes here somehow*/, 'thickness'),
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Width)
```

I want the redux store to still be passed into `mapStateToProps` but also pass `"thickness"`. How do I do that in the `connect()` function?

Comment: Why you need to pass param in `mapStateToProps`? Just declare the `dimenType` anywhere in the file and you can use it in `mapStateToProps`.

Answer (score 9):

Second parameter of `connect` is `ownProps` which are the props passed to `Component`. So in your case you can use it like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let jsonVariable = {}
  for(var i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
    jsonVariable[dimenType + i] = ownProps.dimenType + i
  }
  console.log(jsonVariable)
  return {
    width1: state.get('width').get('width1').toString(),
    width2: state.get('width').get('width2').toString(),
    width3: state.get('width').get('width3').toString()
  }
}
```

I am assuming you are creating your Component like this: `<Width thickness={10}/>`

Comment: Thanks. Could you post the connect statement? I'm a little unsure how to pass the state and then the second parameter to `mapStateToProps` inside `connect()`

Comment: `connect` passes the `state` and `ownProps` to your function you just need to give that function as the first parameter of the `connect` as following: `Width = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Width)`

Comment: I'm not wanting to pass in a number representing thickness. I'm wanting to pass in the string "thickness" or the string "width" and change the store key depending on that string passed in. So replace every word width in my `mapStateToProps` function with "thickness". Because if I don't do that, I end up with 2 exactly the same components and I have to do a search and replace with width and thickness which is code duplication.

Comment: But maybe I can do this: `<measurement measurementType={"thickness"}/>`

Comment: The main point is `connect` function can access to real props of your component, so you can use any `prop` passed. If you can compute a value by a certain parameter, you are right you don't need to pass the computed value to your component.